# click in buttons in list view

Tags: java, android, xml, list, listview

i have function retrieve information (Student id -Student name) from database so each item in list will have (text view for student id and student name) with button (delete student) i try to test the button delete student so if the user press it it will display a toast message that have student id but the problem it is not work and there is no error in console or even the log cat so what do you think how can i solve it ?

also i try to make the code of buttons outside the list but it display an error
how do you think i can solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you set a listener to a View inside ListView.
In your `Adapter`, in the `getView()` method, you need to set the the `clickListener`. Be sure to remove the `setOnItemClickListener` from the ListView.

Comment: ListView lv = getListView();
lv.clickListener ? there is no method could you help me more

Comment: NONONO... Don't you use an Adapter?

Comment: so what should i do can you specify

Comment: you should customize the adapter class that u use for binding the data and then provide the implementation there as you did in onItemClick...